# I need help creating an average method

Tags: java, methods

I need assistance in creating an average method. I have completed everything else. It needs to compute and return the average of all students’ test score averages. I only have the return statement. I am having trouble coming up with the actual method though. Here is my code so far. The first one is for the Course class, the second is the Student class.

```
public class Course  
{
private String course;
private Student s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;
private int studentcount = 0;

public Course (String name)
{
course = name;
}

public Student addStudent(String first, String last, Address home, Address school)
{

if (studentcount == 0){
  s1 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
  studentcount++;          
  return s1;
}    

 if (studentcount == 1) {
  s2 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
      studentcount++;
  return s2;

}
else if (studentcount == 2){
  s3 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
  studentcount++;
      return s3;

}
else if (studentcount == 3){
  s4 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
      studentcount++;
  return s4;

}
else if (studentcount == 4) {
  s5 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
      studentcount++;
  return s5;

}
else { //the course can only have five students
    System.out.println("No More students allowed in the class");
    return null;
}

}

public double average() //returns the average
{
   return (s1.average() + s1.average() + s1.average() + s1.average() + s1.average()) / 5.0;
 }

public String roll() //returns student info for each number of students
{
 String results = "";

if (studentcount == 1){
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  return results;
}    

 if (studentcount == 2) {
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  return results;

}
else if (studentcount == 3){
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  results += s3.toString () +"n";
  return results;

}
else if (studentcount == 4){
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  results += s3.toString () +"n";
  results += s4.toString () +"n";
  return results;

}
else if (studentcount == 5) {
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  results += s3.toString () +"n";
  results += s4.toString () +"n";
  results += s5.toString () +"n";

  return results;
    } 
    else{
  return null;
 }   

 }
 }


public class Student
{
private String firstName, lastName;
private Address homeAddress, schoolAddress;
private int test1, test2, test3;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Sets up this Student object with the specified initial values.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public Student (String first, String last, Address home, Address school)
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    homeAddress = home;
    schoolAddress = school;
    test1 = 0;
    test2 = 0;
    test3 = 0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Returns this Student object as a string.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
 public String toString()
 {
    String result;
    result = firstName + " " + lastName + "\n";
    result += "Home Address:\n" + homeAddress + "\n";
    result += "School Address:\n" + schoolAddress;
    return result;
 }

 public void setTestScore(int t, int g) //sets the test score
 {
   if (t == 1)
   {
       test1 = g;
   }
    else if (t == 2)
    {
        test2 = g;
   }  
    else if (t == 3)
    {
        test3 = g;
   }
 }

 public int getTestScore (int t) //returns the test score
 {
   if (t == 1)
   {
       return test1;
    }
    else if (t == 2)
    {
        return test2;
    }
    else 
    {
        return test3;
    } 
 }
 }
```

Comment: You really need to learn for loop.

Comment: I don't understand why this is getting down votes. My question is clear and I did attempt the rest of the program

Comment: I didn't think it was you. it's just towards whoever did. if this is too broad, what do you suggest? sorry I am pretty new

Comment: "*My question is clear*" not qute. You give us requirements, not question. You need to describe problem you are facing. Also you should avoid posting your full code, you should create [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) instead. BTW don't get discourage when your question will be put on-hold. It can still be reopened if you correct its quality.

Comment: It's not clear at all

Comment: What do you want?  To solve your java exception?  Which part is causing any issue?  If you only know how to use if/else, and you have not used loops or arrays, you will need to add 5 more if statements in your average method.

Comment: Too convoluted code. When you need to hold more than one object (Student here), declaring multiple fields (student1, student2...) is the *dumbest* thing you can do. Use a container (Array or List) and loops. This simplifies and shortens the code.

Comment: @TheUnicornMaster `I only have the return statement. Here is my code so far` I can see many return statements. You just cut all other parts and edit to precise and clear.

Comment: @Durandal I'm not supposed to be using Array yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that exercises like this one should be given to beginners. It will (as can be seen here) entice them to produce repetitive code which is tiresome and annoying. Programming languages have been developed to make programming easy, not a pain in the neck.

OTOH, a problem with a restriction as we have it here (no array) can be seen as an incentive to develop a strategy to make do without the "forbidden" feature. But then again, I wonder whether an introduction to programming should delve into such niceties at such an early stage.

That said, I present a rewrite of class Student. See the comments.

**// The use of arrays and Lists is forbidden.**

```
public class Course {
    private String course;
    private Student s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;
    private int studentcount = 0;

    public Course (String name) {
        course = name;
    }
```

Method addStudent uses the simple trick of "shifting" already stored students to make room for the next Student at `s1`. Although some null values are needlessly copied, this isn't more expensive that repeated tests and certainly less error-prone.

```
    public Student addStudent(String first, String last, String home, String school){
        if( studentcount < 5 ){
            studentcount++;
            s5 = s4; s4 = s3; s3 = s2; s2 = s1;
            return s1 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
        }    
        System.out.println("No more students allowed in the class");
        return null;
    }
```

Method roll uses another standard trick to avoid repetition of lines. Data from `s1` must be presented for all studentcounts greater 1, `s2` must be printed for all counts greater 2, etc. Repeatedly extending a string should be avoided, hence the StringBuilder.

```
    public String roll(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (studentcount >= 1)  sb.append( s1.toString() ).append( "\n" );
        if (studentcount >= 2)  sb.append( s2.toString() ).append( "\n" );
        if (studentcount >= 3)  sb.append( s3.toString() ).append( "\n" );
        if (studentcount >= 4)  sb.append( s4.toString() ).append( "\n" );
        if (studentcount >= 5)  sb.append( s5.toString() ).append( "\n" );
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

The `average` method uses the same technique, now accumulating the scores. Note the conversion to double for computing the quotient.

```
    public double average(){
        int scores = 0;
        if (studentcount >= 1)  
            scores += s1.getTestScore(1) + s1.getTestScore(2) + s1.getTestScore(3);
        if (studentcount >= 2)  
            scores += s2.getTestScore(1) + s2.getTestScore(2) + s2.getTestScore(3);
        if (studentcount >= 3)  
            scores += s3.getTestScore(1) + s3.getTestScore(2) + s3.getTestScore(3);
        if (studentcount >= 4)  
            scores += s4.getTestScore(1) + s4.getTestScore(2) + s4.getTestScore(3);
        if (studentcount >= 5)  
            scores += s5.getTestScore(1) + s5.getTestScore(2) + s5.getTestScore(3);
        return (double)scores/(studentcount*3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If I could vote up more than one, I would. However, I now have a small issue in public Student addStudent.. In this line:    return s1 = new Student(first,last,home,school);                          It says incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Address. home is highlighted.